# Javascript mystery command

Tags: javascript, command

I am new to JavaScript and have to work out what a program does. In it two integers are compared with this inequality: <<=
I don't know what it is and I can't find any online tutorials which tell me.
Thanks
Finlay Perry

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the code in context.

Comment: `<<=` is not a comparison it is a shift and the result is stored in the left variable. It may be inside and if like `if (a <<= 3) ...` but that just check if the result of `a << 3` is not zero and stores the result back in `a` for later use.

Answer (score 1):

It updates the lvalue by left-shifting it by the value on the right.

```
var a = 1;
a <<= 2; // leftshift it by 2 bits,
         // in effect multiplying it by 4, making it 4

a  += 1; // a more common (familiar?) example of this kind of operator
         // add 1, making it 5
```

Answer (score 0):

This is javascript bitwise left shift with assignment. Example of javascript bitwise operators usage:

```
// helper function for displaing results
var output = function(operator, result) {
    console.log(operator + " " + result);
}

// variables
var a = 5;
var b = 13;

// a | b - OR
// if in any of the given numbers corresponding bit 
// is '1', then the result is '1'
output('or', a|b); // 13

// a & b - AND
// if in both of the given numbers corresponding bit 
// is '1', then the result is '1'
output('and', a&b); // 5 

// a ^ b - XOR
// if in one of the given numbers (not both) 
// corresponding bit is '1', then the result is '1'
output('xor', a^b); // 8

// ~a - NOT
// inverts all the bits
output('not', ~a); // -6

// a >> b - RIGHT SHIFT
// shift binary representation of 'a' for 'b' 
// bits to the right, discarding bits shifted off
output('rs', a>>b); // 0

// a << b - LEFT SHIFT
// shift binary representation of 'a' for 'b' 
// bits to the right, shifting in zeros from the right
output('ls', a<<b); // 40960

// a >>> b - ZERO FILLED RIGHT SHIFT
// shift binary representation of 'a' for 'b' 
// bits to the right, discarding bits shifted off, 
// and shifting in zeros from the left.
output('zfrs', a>>>b); // 0
```